# not able to run hpa, get metrics to api metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, heapster

I am trying to run horizontal pod autoscaler in kubernetes, want to auto scale my pods based on cpu default metrics.
For that I installed metrics server after that I can see metrics - metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 (`kubectl api-versions`). Then I tried deploying prometheus-operator. But upon runnning `kubectl top node/pod` - error I am getting is

```
error: Metrics not available for pod default/web-deployment-658cd556f8-ztf6c, age: 35m23.264812635s" and "error: metrics not available yet"
```

Do I need to run heapster?

Answer (score 0):

In minikube, we have to enable metrics-server add-on.

```
minikube addons list

minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

Then create hpa, deployment and boom!!

Anyone has done autoscaling based on custom metrics? like based on no. of http requests?

Answer (score 0):

@batman, as you said enabling minikube metrics-server add-on is enough in case of using minikube.

In general case, if using metrics-server you edited the metrics server deployment by running: `kubectl edit deployment metrics-server -n kube-system`

Under `spec:` -> `containers:` add following flag:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /metrics-server
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

As described on [metrics-server github](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/):

> `--kubelet-insecure-tls`: skip verifying Kubelet CA certificates. Not recommended for production usage, but can be useful in test clusters
>   with self-signed Kubelet serving certificates.

[Here](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-autoscaling-custom-metrics/) you can find tutorial describing HPA using custom metrics and Prometheus.